# Обновление пакета Chocolatey

Tags: windows

Вот поставил я `choco install gradle` и поставилась 3.1 версия. А на сайте уже 3.4 есть. Возможно ли как-то обновить средствами choco версию?

Comment: речь о Windows и Chocolatey?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да

Comment: Чтобы установить не проверенный модераторами пакет, укажите его версию, [**см. документацию**](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/ChocolateyFAQs#how-do-i-install-an-unlisted-package--package-version). В Вашем случае: `choco install gradle --version 3.4.1 -y` →  у меня успешно установилось. Помните, что устанавливаете непроверенные версии на свой страх и риск. Спасибо.

Comment: Да, там сейчас нехватка модераторов. мои Chocolatey пакеты модераторы проверяют где-то через 3 недели после запушивания. Ждать, пока они проверят, вряд ли стоит; лучше делайте, как написал в комментарии вышел. Спасибо.